# Using Proxy with Gradle when accessing certain maven repositories only?

Tags: maven, proxy, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a custom maven repo where I host some private maven repositories. In order to access the repository it requires a username and password, and also it requires connection through a proxy.

The problem is, I don't want ALL my gradle traffic going through this proxy. Is there a way to configure it so that only for specific repositories it will go through the proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Proxy configuration in Gradle happens via standard JVM system properties (`http.proxyHost` etc.). As such there is no way to configure a proxy for a specific repository.

PS: Maven repositories are best hosted on a Maven repository server/service (Artifactory, Nexus, [Bintray](http://bintray.com)).

Comment: There is also `http.nonProxyHosts` as desribed in networking properties http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html

Comment: @Radim Perfect. You want to make an answer so I can mark that as correct?